# Graduate from university in X

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-structure

I know I could say:

> I graduated in mathematics from XZ University.

But what if want to put emphasis only on the field of my study (mathematics) without specifying the university?

Could I say that?

> I graduated in mathematics from (a) university.

I just want to express that I have a university education in mathematics. I know I could also say that I hold a degree but I am just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would  leave "from a university" out of the sentence.

> I graduated with a degree in mathematics.

or

> I graduated in mathematics.

or

> My (undergraduate) degree is in mathematics.

This is rather unidiomatic:

> I graduated in mathematics from a university.

Comment: In the second sentence, is a university-level implied?

Comment: Yes, because we don't specialize in secondary school, and if we're talking about a graduate degree, the usual thing to say is "I have an advanced degree in ..."